# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

Tags: android, start-activity

I am writing an application where `Activity A` launches `Activity B` using

```
startActivityForResult(intent, -101);
```

but when called, it responded back with following error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1708): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
E/AndroidRuntime( 1708):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:837)
```

Probably it could be **-101** but I am not sure. Does any one have any idea on this?

Comment: Change -101 to a positive number?

Comment: Can only use lower 16  for requestCode : means request code should be >0 
try  startActivityForResult(intent, 101);

Comment: Try this solution :https://stackoverflow.com/a/44271392/2267723

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to pass a positive number to `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: Although this is true, answers below are more specific. +1

Answer (score 141):

You get this exception only in `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and not when you use `android.app.Activity`.

`startActivityForResult()` in `FragmentActivity` requires the `requestCode` to be of 16 bits, meaning the range is from 0 to 65535.

Also, `validateRequestPermissionsRequestCode` in `FragmentActivity` requires `requestCode` to be of 16 bits, meaning the range is from 0 to 65535.

For more info(if you want to see the source code) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331459/4747587

Comment: Thanks Henry, this is a more complete answer

Answer (score 91):

If you're using `ActivityResult` APIs, add this dependency to fix this issue:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.4"
```

Comment: Thank you! You should really put this into a self-answered question so other people can find it easily.

Comment: somehow and I really do not know why. but,
You should add these two dependencies together.

implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:x.x.x'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:x.x.x'

Comment: Why they told us how many dependencies required to have new features? Google docs sucks! Thanks by the way for helping.

Comment: No idea why the error isn't more specific. At any rate, thank you. My hero <3

Answer (score 35):

It is also good to mention that this may happen if you use a number greater than 2^16 / 2 (which is 32768), so there's basically 2^15 options to not to screw this up.

Explanation: 16 bits can represent one of 65536 numbers, however, half of them are negative.

Comment: The limit is 65535 and not 32768.

Comment: @Henry Yes, negatif numbers are unused

Answer (score 28):

For those who are using the new ActivityResult API,

If you are using the new way (ActivityResult) to open new Activity.

```
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { 
    result ->
}
```

you have to use both of the below dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-rc02'
```

Comment: It's kind of odd to use fragment implementation when not using it. But it works with it

Comment: I think stable version will solve the problem

Comment: @Shaon i have to disappoint you.. they dont

Comment: This whole changes just messing things more and more.

Answer (score 14):

You can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode means -- in binary terms -- you can use

`0000000000000000 (16 bits) to 1111111111111111 (16 bits)` [ binary ].

Or, equivalently

`0 to 65535` [ base 10 ].

In decimal ("number") terms, this allows for `2^16 = 65536` combinations. Therefore, you can only use the numbers 0 all the way through 65535.

You also cannot use negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The right answer is that you should use a 16 bits number for this purpose. 
The most safe solution for that is to always set your request code as `short`. If programmer attempts to write number more than 16 bits then the IDE won't let you to proceed because there will be an error.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the two main dependencies for activityforresult API

for kotlin

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0'
```

for java

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.3.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0'
```

check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity) for the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

for kotlin

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.3'
```