# Pick Contacts onClick when Button is pressed Android

Tags: java, android, contacts, contactpicker

Im having issues with my App. What i'd like to do is when my Button is pressed to open my Phone Contatcs and display them to my TextViews. I have issues when i perform the Button Press i think.

At least LogCat is saying me some Error with my Button but i can't figure out whats wrong.

In my Manifestfile i've already set the permissions for reading and writing contacts. I have a ContactView.java where the Code happens and i've already created the view with Button and 2 textView's.

Maybe someone can help me or at least tell me what im doing wrong.

In my view i said: android:onClick="pickContact"

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactView extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int RESULT_PICK_CONTACT = 85500;
private TextView textView1;
private TextView textView2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_view);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtName);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtNumber);
}
public void pickContact(View v)
{
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // check whether the result is ok
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple startActivityForReslut
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:
                contactPicked(data);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ContactView", "Failed to pick contact");
    }
}
/**
 * Query the Uri and read contact details. Handle the picked contact data.
 * @param data
 */
private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null ;
        String name = null;
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the phone number
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        // column index of the contact name
        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        // Set the value to the textviews
        textView1.setText(name);
        textView2.setText(phoneNo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what LogCat says after i press my addcontacts Button while debugging:

```
    10-18 23:11:08.684    4353-4353/me.resq.resqme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: me.resq.resqme, PID: 4353
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:746)
                at me.resq.resqme.ContactView.pickContact(ContactView.java:28)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static final int RESULT_PICK_CONTACT = 85500;
```

Please try to change it to something lower like:

```
private static final int RESULT_PICK_CONTACT = 85;
```

Comment: actually worked ... is this the correct way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: @idunnowhatimdoin I hadn't read your entire stack trace, my answer was wrong so I deleted it.  More explanation on what's going on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529865/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-can-only-use-lower-16-bits-for-requestcode