# Android app crash: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

Tags: java, android

I just released an app on the play store and have gotten a crash report from a galaxy note 4 with this stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
at android.support.v4.app.q.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.q.startIntentSenderForResult(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.x.startIntentSenderForResult(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ba.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I have tested my app on multiple devices and have never gotten an error like this! I do have proguard on which i believe may be the culprit? What do you guys think? The app crashed on the first activity and i only have one requestCode whose value is 111. I don't understand why i could be getting this exception. Google sign in is implemented in the first activity and here is where the requestCode is being used:

```
private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 111 ; (instance variable)



private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: First I see of this error. Seems weird. Hope you find a solution, upvoted for others to see.

Comment: Are you sure your SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE is 111? It seems that is not the case.

Comment: Yes, it is 111 I just checked again, the weird thing is that it's only crashing on a few devices.

Comment: Can proguard play any role in this?

Comment: There is high probability, If you have access to those devices, I would add log to your code and monitor this value while running your code. I am pretty sure that wouldn't be 111.

Comment: I don't have access to the device that reported the trace and i don't believe i can emulate a galaxy note 4!

Comment: If anyone is willing to try my app and see if it works on their device i would really appreciate it!  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magnetdev.magnet

Comment: @sameer54321 can yout edit your question with your `SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE` declaration ? The error is related to this variable, so if we see all the uses of the variable maybe we can find something

Comment: what in this stack trace makes you point to this signIn() code as the possible culprit?  This appears to be related to Google Play Services.

Comment: @CSmith this is where the request code is being used but yes you are correct it may be an issue with Google Play Services.

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro Added the declaration for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some others questions in the SO with the same problem, seems for some Reason your request code is greater than the maximum you can.

The problem occurs in only few devices may be because the problem is solved in later versions.

This code is from the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`:

```
/**
* Modifies the standard behavior to allow results to be delivered to fragments.
* This imposes a restriction that requestCode be <= 0xffff.
*/
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode != -1 && (requestCode&0xffff0000) != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode");
    }
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

The code above throw a exception if your problem will occurs, so you can test in any device, just override the method on your activity.

I have seem in a comment that the problem may not occurs if you use an `Integer` beside an `int`

Another workaround may be use some of the APP Compat Libraries.

[Link to the post with the answer above.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331073/android-what-to-choose-for-requestcode-values/33331459)