# Android - What is the correct way of keeping track of multiple PendingIntents?

Tags: android, push-notification, kotlin, android-pendingintent

I'll explain briefly what I need to achieve, I have used the `PendingIntent` in combination with `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` to notify the user every week.

```
val notificationAlarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
val notificationIntent = Intent(this, ReminderBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
val pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 549078, notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
 myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10)
 notificationAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myCalendar.timeInMillis, notificationOffset(sub.cycle),
                    pendingNotificationIntent)
```

As you can see now I am forcing the `549078` as a `resultCode` in the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

What is the correct way to differenciate between the result codes, so that I not only can have multiple notifications (since the same resultCode will be overwritten when I create a new one) but I also need a way to keep track of the result code, because I may want to delete it before it is being shown.

Comment: "Result code" is something that comes back from starting an activity for result. I assume you mean pending intent request code. You may want to update your question accordingly.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman yes, you are right, I mean request code, will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to query the `AlarmManager` for the  `PendingIntent`s. You must store the `resultCode` and other information to recreate the `PendingIntent` in order to delete it.

For example in [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) or in a database like SqliteDB or Room. Then you can recreate the PendingIntent to cancel it.

See [how to cancel PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315611/android-get-all-pendingintents-set-with-alarmmanager).

See [How does android compare pending intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520951/how-does-android-compare-pending-intents) for details on what fields are important when comparing the intents for deletion.

Comment: ok I see, should I just use an incremental request code or should I find some criteria and build it from there?

Comment: If it makes sense for your app an incremental request code is fine. If you have some Alarms that are always the same you can use the same code for them, that way only you can make sure that only one alarm of that type can be present at a time.

Comment: One thing, if you use Fragments the code must be below 65535 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331073/android-what-to-choose-for-requestcode-values/33331459

Comment: I will keep that in mind and implement this tomorrow, thanks a lot

Comment: ok I found a way to have a unique `requestCode` for every notification, what are the "other information" I need to store that you are talking about exactly? Now quite getting how to cancel the intent

Comment: see [`AlarmManager.cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent))

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, what I did was as follow:

1) I created an int field which I create in my main activity as a static field.

2) I get the value of this variable in `onCreate()` of the main activity from the application database.

3) Every time I am creating a new alarm I get a new request code through a function as follows:

```
public static int getRequestCode() {
    int temp = this.requestCode++;
    // Update the database value with the current requestCode value
    return temp;
}
```

4) In my case I added a new field to the alarm class called requestCode so I can keep track of which request code is for which alarm as I am already saving the alarms in my database, for your case I am not sure how exactly is your application but I guess you need to find a way to store this value for each alarm.

I am not sure this will be very helpful since I am not sure if you are using a database for your app or not, but I recommend you consider creating one, even a local one if you don't care about having your data on a server yet *( you can use Room Library for that and it's very straight forward, here's a link https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room )* as I believe this will definitely create you many problems on the long run, since the system doesn't really create a new PendingIntent when you initiate one, it returns the exciting token if all parameters match

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: That will fail if your process is killed. You will lose your static counter. It's also not clear why you'd write the value to the DB if you never read it.

Comment: Exactly for this reason I save it to my database, as I get the value for this counter *(as mentioned in step 2)* from the database `onCreate()`. So when my process is killed, on re-start the value will be retrieved from database with the last value it had and and I will increment from there again not from the beginning. Also as mentioned in another answer, SharedPreferences should be a good way to store it as well.

Comment: Why not have one single method for accessing the value?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Can you please clarify? @JeffreyBlattman

Comment: Yea now I get it. Well I am actually not taking the value manually on start, I just assign it in the `onChildAdded` method in Firebase `ChildListener`, but I am considering moving it locally as I started to realize it might create bugs later on. Thanks for the hint though, appreciated :)