# Using "id" as requestCode for "startActivityForResult" from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, startactivityforresult

[Android Docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiK5ru5y7XgAhWF0KYKHTgJDmwQFjABegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fresources%2Fmore-resources&usg=AOvVaw00rRi80Fq8KRDsiPy2VhBs) say in about `ID XML resource`:

> A **unique** resource ID defined in XML. [...] which you can use as [...] unique integer for use in your application code (for example, as an ID for a dialog or a result code).

I created `request` in `ids.xml`

```
<item name="request" type="id" />
```

Its value is `-1000003`. I want to use it as `requestCode` for `startActivityForResult` from `FragmentActivity`. But as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331459/1043882), `requestCode` must be of *16 bits*, meaning the range is from **0** to **65535**. So the value of `request` is not valid (it is negative and also exceeds bounds range). and using it causes this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
```

Although I can use arbitrary valid integer, but its uniqueness may be violated during time of application maintaining/developing. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: The error is right, you can use it as `result code` (as documentation says), not as `requestCode `

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yes, but I want to be sure that my requestCode is unique.

Comment: any reason you want it to be unique?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Today I use an arbitrary `requestCode` and after debugging found that its value was the same the value of another `requestCode` which was set in another file.

Comment: Just use some `Constants.java` class, where you just define all the request codes to be sure they are unique

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yes, it seems it is the only way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your value is a negative number but range is of positive numbers only.
This error is might be because of this reason

Comment: I know that. But also it exceeds bounds range.