# FCM: Gradle failed to resolve firebase-core library

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 Beta and trying to pull down the latest firebase libraries for cloud messinging but keeps running into errors.

> failed to resolve:
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0

Any ideas what I need to do? I have Android SDK 6 and 7, Tools (Preview Channel), and Tools (Rev. 23, 24, 25) installed. I'm stuck hard.

Comment: From https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

        // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

you really need to do it in that order. add it in the bottom

Comment: I think [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529865/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-can-only-use-lower-16-bits-for-requestcode) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Menu bar > Tools > Android > SDK Manager
Click on Tab > SDK Tools
Check and install 'Google Play Services' and 'Google Repository'
Now, click Sync and build your project again.