# How Do I Create A Contact Picker Activity?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm a novice coder and I've been trying to learn how to code for school in a few days and one thing I like to do is try and deconstruct other code to learn it better. So I was looking at trying to make a contact picker and I found a tutorial online, however, the code does not work, and I don't really understand what the error message means.

My code:

```
public class ContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static final int RESULT_PICK_CONTACT = 85500;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
}

public void pickContact(View v)
{
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // check whether the result is ok
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple startActivityForReslut
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:
                contactPicked(data);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to pick contact");
    }
}
/**
 * Query the Uri and read contact details. Handle the picked contact data.
 * @param data
 */
private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null ;
        String name = null;
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the phone number
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        // column index of the contact name
        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        // Set the value to the textviews
        b1.setText(name);
        b2.setText(phoneNo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Error Message:

```
08-14 16:25:16.437 3923-3923/com.example.jackson.safetynet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jackson.safetynet, PID: 3923
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.checkForValidRequestCode(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:79)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:748)
    at com.example.jackson.safetynet.ContactActivity.pickContact(ContactActivity.java:29)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

So I see the line "  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode  " and I think that this is the problem. Is there something with the Result_Pick_Contact or what?

[Layout Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oq7z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a smaller positive `RESULT_PICK_CONTACT` value

```
private static final int RESULT_PICK_CONTACT = 24;
```

[As specified by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529865/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-can-only-use-lower-16-bits-for-requestcode)

> You need to pass a positive number to startActivityForResult.