# Why onActivityResult() only invoked when requestCode>=0?

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

As we can know, the `startActivity` method will be invoked `startActivityForResult` method; And some code like as below:

```
    /**
 * Same as calling {@link #startActivityForResult(Intent, int, Bundle)}
 * with no options.
 *
 * @param intent The intent to start.
 * @param requestCode If >= 0, this code will be returned in
 *                    onActivityResult() when the activity exits.
 *
 * @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
 *
 * @see #startActivity
 */
public void startActivityForResult(@RequiresPermission Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, null);
}
```

I try my best to find the source code where deal the requestCode. But I found nothing. Could somebody can copy the source code and tell me how it deal with when only requestCode>=0the OnActivityResult() invoked?

Comment: please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529865/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-can-only-use-lower-16-bits-for-requestcode) link.here it is explained.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the code snippet you included, the two-parameter version of `startActivityForResult` calls into a three-parameter version of `startActivityForResult`. The three-parameter version [looks like this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#4582):

```
public void startActivityForResult(@RequiresPermission Intent intent, int requestCode, @Nullable Bundle options) {
    if (mParent == null) {
        //...
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
            mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
                this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
                intent, requestCode, options);
        if (ar != null) {
            mMainThread.sendActivityResult(
                mToken, mEmbeddedID, requestCode, ar.getResultCode(),
                ar.getResultData());
        }
        if (requestCode >= 0) {
            // If this start is requesting a result, we can avoid making
            // the activity visible until the result is received.  Setting
            // this code during onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) or onResume() will keep the
            // activity hidden during this time, to avoid flickering.
            // This can only be done when a result is requested because
            // that guarantees we will get information back when the
            // activity is finished, no matter what happens to it.
            mStartedActivity = true;
        }

        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

The comment in the `if (requestCode >= 0) {}` block describes how behavior changes when the request code is `>= 0` vs `< 0`.

If we look at [the source code for `mInstrumentation.execStartActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/core/java/android/app/Instrumentation.java#1635), we find the following:

```
public ActivityResult execStartActivity(
        Context who, IBinder contextThread, IBinder token, Activity target,
        Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {

    //...

                    if (am.isBlocking()) {
                        return requestCode >= 0 ? am.getResult() : null;
                    }

    // ...
}
```

The line `return requestCode >= 0 ? am.getResult() : null;` returns a `null` `ActivityResult` if the `requestCode` is negative. Jumping back to the `startActivityForResult` code at the top of this answer, we see that `mMainThread.sendActivityResult` is called if and only if the `ActivityResult` returned by `execStartActivity` is non-`null`. It is `sendActivityResult` that eventually results in a call to `onActivityResult`. So the path of logic here is:

`startActivityForResult` is called with a negative `requestCode`
↳ `mInstrumentation.execStartActivity` is called with a negative `requestCode`
↳ `mInstrumentation.execStartActivity` returns `null`
↳ `mMainThread.sendActivityResult` is NOT called
↳ `onActivityResult` is NOT called