# New result API error : Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

Tags: android, android-jetpack, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

Today I switched to the new `ResultAPI` and I faced this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.checkForValidRequestCode(FragmentActivity.java:715)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:673)
    at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:207)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$3.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:147)
    at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:42)
    at .MainActivity.getVideo(MainActivity.kt:61)
    at .MainActivity.access$getVideo(MainActivity.kt:18)
    at .MainActivity$onCreate$2.onClick(MainActivity.kt:42)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5232)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21289)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

When executing these lines:

```
private val takeFile = registerForActivityResult(GetContent()) {
    Log.e("MainActivity", "fileName: $it")
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    btn_get_video.setOnClickListener {
        getVideo()
    }

}


private fun getVideo() {
    takeFile.launch("video/*")
}
```

There is no way to declare `REQUEST_CODE` manually with this new result API.

**NOTICE:**
It sometimes works!

**[UPDATE]**
I registered multiple contracts (TakeVideo & GetContent) and I found that the order of registration is important (the first one works like a charm but the others will crash). **maybe we have to register just a single contract for each activity?!**

**[UPDATE #2]**
The problem has been fixed in the latest version of activity (1.2.7-alpha07). now it's warning you about adding both activity and fragment related dependencies.

Comment: What is the version of your fragment dependency?

Comment: Have the same problem but with TakePicture. Version is 1.2.0-alpha06 for activity

Comment: I just added activity dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529865/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-can-only-use-lower-16-bits-for-requestcode)

Comment: @Cristan, yes but actually no. That question has answer with precise description of the source of the problem. But here `REQUEST_CODE` is generated by the library, not the developer. And it keeps generating the wrong value for it.

Comment: Just got this with `1.2.0-beta01` and no fragments in use at all!

Comment: 1.2.0-beta01 && 1.2.0-alpha08 giving same error. Anyone fixed this?

Comment: From my limited testing, it looks like you need to add the androidx.fragment library (see below) even if you don't actually use fragments. No idea why...

Answer (score 29):

Add or update to this dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0'
```

When using `ActivityResult` APIs, use this fragment dependency to ensure that `FragmentActivity` is compatible.

Comment: A lint warning will be given regarding this starting from Activity 1.2.0-alpha07

Answer (score 4):

I think something is wrong with the new API. In **`ActivityResultRegistry`** you can see :

```
 /**
 * Generate a random number between the initial value (00010000) inclusive, and the max
 * integer value. If that number is already an existing request code, generate another until
 * we find one that is new.
 *
 * @return the number
 */
private int generateRandomNumber() {
    int number = mRandom.nextInt((Integer.MAX_VALUE - INITIAL_REQUEST_CODE_VALUE) + 1)
            + INITIAL_REQUEST_CODE_VALUE;
    while (mRcToKey.containsKey(number)) {
        number = mRandom.nextInt((Integer.MAX_VALUE - INITIAL_REQUEST_CODE_VALUE) + 1)
                + INITIAL_REQUEST_CODE_VALUE;
    }
    return number;
}
```

In debugged mode i saw "1388473134" sent for request code. Now lets see what is happening. In this case we are using  `ActivityResultRegistry` provided
by the framework. This generate a request code hold by the framework and generated by **`generateRandomNumber`** from **`ActivityResultRegistry`**.

See in **`ComponentActivity`** class of google framework `androidx.activity`.

```
private ActivityResultRegistry mActivityResultRegistry = new ActivityResultRegistry() {

    @Override
    public <I, O> void onLaunch(
            final int requestCode,
            @NonNull ActivityResultContract<I, O> contract,
            I input,
            @Nullable ActivityOptionsCompat options) {

            ...
            
        } else {
            // startActivityForResult path
            ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(activity, intent, requestCode, optionsBundle);
        }
}
```

This will call **`checkForValidRequestCode`** from `FragmentActivity` and throw an exception (because the request code generate is too "hight").

```
@Override
    public void startActivityForResult(@SuppressLint("UnknownNullness") Intent intent,
            int requestCode, @Nullable Bundle options) {
        // If this was started from a Fragment we've already checked the upper 16 bits were not in
        // use, and then repurposed them for the Fragment's index.
        if (!mStartedActivityFromFragment) {
            if (requestCode != -1) {
                checkForValidRequestCode(requestCode);
            }
        }
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, options);
    }
```

To remove the issue you have to update the source of `checkForValidRequestCode` provided in `androidx.fragment.app` in your build gradele with a fresh version of this method.

In your gradle file

```
dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.3.0-beta02"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    // Testing Fragments in Isolation
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
}
```