# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode

Tags: android

I USE THIS CODE

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0-rc01")

val permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
    for (data in it){
        Log.e(TAG, data.toString())
    }
}
permissionLauncher.launch(arrayOf(
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
))
```

ERR

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.checkForValidRequestCode(FragmentActivity.java:715)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.validateRequestPermissionsRequestCode(FragmentActivity.java:730)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New result API error : Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771948/new-result-api-error-can-only-use-lower-16-bits-for-requestcode)

Comment: lib version ? change "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:XXX"  implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:xxx") ?