# ActivityResultLauncher successfully launch the ActivityResultContracts the first time on AppCompatActivity , but crashes at the second time

Tags: android, android-activity

What I am using is the new features of androidx.activity:

```
activity_version = "1.2.0-alpha06"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity:$activity_version"
```

Assume that there is a button. When I click it, it displays the images directory, and I can select several images at a time. After confirming the selection, I get a list of uris of selected images. The code looks like this:

```
package com.example.test_contracts;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button test_button=findViewById(R.id.test_button);
        test_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents contracts=new ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents();

                ActivityResultLauncher<String> launcher=registerForActivityResult(contracts, new ActivityResultCallback<List<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(List<Uri> result) {
                        //.....do something with the list of urls
                    }
                });

                launcher.launch("image/*");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**This piece of code runs perfectly on Fragment, but when running on AppCompatActivity, some weird things occur, as I describe in title**: the first time when I click the button, the images directory appears. After I comfirm the selection, return to the previous activity and click the button again, the app will crash immediately. **The exception says: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode.**

So I try to figure out why this happen. After setting a lot of breakpoints, I find that when I apply this piece of code **on AppCompatActivity, the requestcode will be initally set to 65535, on the class ActivityResultRegistry; And when I launch the activity again, the requestcode +1 and set to 65536, which leads to the Exception.**

```
 private final AtomicInteger mNextRc = new AtomicInteger(0x0000ffff);
```

So I basically know a little about the cause. But why they set the requestcode so large? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62775427/7746134

Comment: @Saurabh Thorat That's amazing!!! I can never image it is the absence of the implementation that makes this problem....After adding the implemention, it won't crash anymore!